# Issues Connecting WalletConnect in a React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3modal

community! I've been encountering issues when trying to integrate WalletConnect into my React application. Attempting to connect a wallet via WalletConnect, I face WebSocket connection errors and fail to load resources from bridge.walletconnect.org.

Ensured I'm using the latest version of @walletconnect/web3-provider.
Verified the bridge URL is correctly specified in my code (bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org').
Restarted the development server and cleared the browser cache.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';
import WalletConnectProvider from '@walletconnect/web3-provider';

function WalletConnect() {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState('');

  const providerOptions = {
    walletconnect: {
      package: WalletConnectProvider,
      options: {
        bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
        rpc: {
          1: 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/мой_INFURA_API_KEY'
        }
      }
    }
  };

  async function connectWallet() {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
      network: "mainnet",
      cacheProvider: true,
      providerOptions
    });

    try {
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
      // дальнейшие действия
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Connection to wallet failed:", error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={connectWallet}>Connect Wallet</button>
      {account && <p>Connected account: {account}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default WalletConnect;
```

**Errors I'm receiving:**

WebSocket connection to 'wss://bridge.walletconnect.org/?env=browser&...' failed.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().
I've searched for solutions in the WalletConnect documentation and forums, but haven't been able to resolve this issue. Any help or guidance on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.